# How to use sql query with IN for a select statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I need to us a sql query in java that has an IN clause in it.  I have seen suggestions for doing this when the IN clause is a predetermined set, such as numbers which won't work in this case because the set will be dynamic.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
select c.cust_name 
from cust_acct c, has h 
where c.cust_id=h.cust_id 
    and h.sh_add in (select a.sh_add from address a where sh_st='VA')
```

I do not get any faults.  That is, the code runs I just get no results for this particular query

Comment: It appears from Mr. E's answer that it is not the IN clause that is causing my problem.  When I use the code that he provided I am getting the same lack of results.  Time to pursue a different path I guess.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that you are getting the right intermediate results from `select a.sh_add from address a where sh_st='VA'`?

You could just rewrite the query as:

```
select c.cust_name 
from cust_acct c
inner join has h 
on c.cust_id=h.cust_id 
inner join address a
on h.sh_add = a.sh_add
where a.sh_st = 'VA'
```

Comment: I have checked it and it does return results.  I just tried your code as well and I am getting the same results.  If I try executing it as sql in the database view of eclipse it returns the proper result but when I try and execute it as part of main I get no result.  This is only one of ten queries and all others are returning properly making me fairly confident that the rest of the code (such as the getString and print) are correct.  Thank you for the suggestion.